# Coordination number 4 corresponds to tetrahedral shape yet NH3 has trigonal pyramidal shape why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

I understand the reason for the trigonal pyramidal shape (presence of lone pair) but if there's a relation between coordination number and geometry of molecules it's violated here isn't it?

Comment: It has a tetrahedral geometry but a trigonal pyramidal shape.There is a difference between geometry and shape.

Comment: If you count all you end up with a distorted tetrahedrun , Isn't?

Comment: NH3 has a coordination number of 3...

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{NH3}$ has a trigonal pyramidal shape because the molecule isn't planar. You only look at the position of the atoms present so the lone pair on the nitrogen atom is irrelevant.

$\ce{NH4^+}$ has a tetrahedron shape with the N in the center.